# CSRF detection for POST request with content type validation at server

Tags: penetration-testing

This is regarding the http request which i am trying to make as a part of PoC for CSRF vulnerability. The obvious way of csrf protection via server realm is not in place.

I tried using XHR object to check the vulnerability. But the server is not configured with CORS as observed in the OPTIONS preflight request made by my browser and subsequent POST request did not happen.

```
<html>
<title>JSON CSRF POC</title>
<body>
<center>
<h1> JSON CSRF POC </h1>
<script>fetch('<url here>', {method: 'POST', credentials: 'include', 
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: '{<Payload in json  
format>}'});
</script>
<form action="#">
<input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I have specified content type as 'plain/text' in my first run. But the server seems to be checking the content type as well and the request erroed out. As specified in the code above, the content-type is 'application/json' which is what server is expecting. But when I run the code, the request is treated as XHR and is not successful. I did try the burp PoC for the csrf using "Auto-select based on the request features" options with the expectation that the generated code will have content type as specified in the intercepted request. But the code has content type set to plain/text. The PoC code also changes the payload in the url encoded format which the server does nopt accept. If i interecpt the http request generated by burp PoC and change the content type to "application/json" and the payload in json format, the request is successful.

Thanks.

My question is :- 
1. After changing the content type to application/json, whay is browser treating it as XHR request? 
2. Is there any way by which i can change the above code so that browser will not treat it as XHR [cross domain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `fetch` is similar implementation as XHR, except that its API uses promises to handle the result. While also browsers do not support content type of JSON for form submissions.
2. You can use a Flash `swf` file which can trigger such requests. See the answer below:
   https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170477/csrf-with-json-post-when-content-type-must-be-application-json?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thanks Trim .. the swf way for exploiting the application server worked for me. This needed more env set up with swf file decoding .... but it did work for my case... Thanks a lot ....

Comment: I am glad it did! It would be good if you mark this as the accepted answer so it will also be shown as resolved in search results.